# EditorAction not triggered for maxLines="1"

Tags: android

Forgive if its a noob question. I replaced `android:singleLine="true"` (deprecated now) with `android:maxLines="1"` and now `setOnEditorActionListener` doesn't seems to fire.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/listItemET"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:text="List Item"/>
```

`EditorActionListener` for the edittext.

```
listItemET.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: If I revert it back to `android:singleLine="true"` everything seems to work fine.

Comment: The docs says : `When used on an editable text, the inputType attribute's value must be combined with the textMultiLine flag for the maxLines attribute to apply.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android:inputType="text"` in the EditText along with maxLines attribute. Example Snippet:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:maxLines="1"     
android:inputType="text"/>    <----- add this
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines) :

> When used on an editable text, the inputType attribute's value must be
>   combined with the textMultiLine flag for the maxLines attribute to
>   apply.

So you should modify your code as :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/listItemET"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:text="List Item"
    android:inputType="text | textMultiLine"/>  // As per the doc says
```